# JavaScript favourite number

Tags: javascript, validation

[the form code where i have to enter he number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLE3W.png)

[after entering the random number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIRzC.png)

I have to code it in console so that it iterated 100 to 999 and validates the favourite number.
I am new to JavaScript and I was stuck with the code.

I have tried this.

```html
document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].getElementsByTagName("number")[0].value = 0;
for(int i=100;i<1000;i++){
document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
value++;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: I wanted to write a loop that validates from 100-999 and then matches the favourite number in the form at the server. Please check the image for more details.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need if I am not wrong:

```
for(int i=100;i<1000;i++){
    document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].getElementsByTagName("number")[0].value = i;
    document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
}
```

In the question, you are increasing value but not assigning it to the `number` `input` of `form`

Also you could enhance you code like this:

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
var number_elem = form.getElementsByTagName("number")[0];
for(var i=100; i<1000; i++){
    number_elem.value = i;
    form.submit();
}
```